# searching through json with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a json file in format

```
{
    "list" : {
           "1" : {
                "thing1" : "description",
                "thing2" : "description",
                "thing3" : "description"
            },
           "2" : {
                "thing1" : "description",
                "thing2" : "description",
                "thing3" : "description"
            },
            etc.

}
```

I need to search through and return data based on the description of thing 2 but I also need to then return the number of the list. Problem is the json file comes in with the numbers all out of order so I can't just increment a variable as I go through them all.

currently I have my code setup like this:

```
$json = json_decode($response);
foreach($json->list as $item) {
        $i++;
        if($item->thing2 == "description") {
            echo "<p>$item->thing1</p>";
            echo "<p>$item->thing2</p>";
            echo "<p>$item->thing3</p>";
            echo "<p>position: $i</p><br /><br />";
        }
    }
```

unfortunately because the positions are out of order everytime the $i variable is retuning the wrong position. How can I return the title of the item that has the proper thing2 description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting the second parameter of `json_decode()` to `TRUE` returns an associative array which is a bit more conducive to what you want to do:

```
$json = json_decode($response, TRUE);
foreach($json['list'] as $key => $item) {
    if($item['thing2'] == "description") {
        echo "<p>$item['thing1']</p>";
        echo "<p>$item['thing2']</p>";
        echo "<p>$item['thing3']</p>";
        echo "<p>position: $key</p><br /><br />";
    }
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: While it's nice to mention the associative array argument, there's no real need for it here . . . foreach will loop over an object as easily as an array.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
foreach($json->list as $item) {
    $i++;
```

to

```
foreach($json->list as $i => $item) {
```

(This is described in the PHP documentation for [object iteration](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php).)

Answer (score -1):

[json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) has the option of returning an associative array (`$assoc = true`). After this, it is trivial to just access `$associative_array["2"]`.